# Is this sentence constructed correctly?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense

> I am experienced in and also willing to conduct/conducting fieldwork.

I want to express the meaning that I am experienced in conducting fieldwork (in the past), and I am also willing to conduct more fieldwork (in the future).

Is my sentence constructed correctly?

Comment: I have done fieldwork in the past  and I am willing to conduct more fieldwork in the future.

Comment: Leaving a long gap between “I am experienced in...” and “fieldwork” makes the sentence harder to read (as anouk has picked up too). I’d avoid repeating “fieldwork” too and “willing” sounds very weak in this context. So a better sentence might be something like, “I am experienced in fieldwork and look forward to furthering that experience.”